# MongoDB: Find documents by range filter performed on array of nested documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter

Consider a collection of documents that collects scores as an array of nested documents, like this (I'm using MongoDb 4.2):

```
{
    "scores" : [
      { "value" : 2 }, 
      { "value" : 3 },
      { "value" : 4 }
    ]
}, {
    "scores" : [
      { "value" : 8  }, 
      { "value" : 9  },
      { "value" : 10 }
    ]
}, {
    "scores" : [
      { "value" : 7  }, 
      { "value" : 7 },
      { "value" : 10 }
    ]
}
```

Consider now the following use case: "Give me all the documents that contains  ONLY scores in the range [X, Y]". Said differently, please filter out the documents that have at least one value that is NOT in the range [X-Y]. Side note: in the actual data, the scores are real numbers, so doing some $in queries won't help here.

Let's consider three ranges:

- Range [8, 10] (one documents should match)
- Range [0, 1]  (0 document matching).
- Range [5, 6]  (0 document matching).

As a non-expert yet in mongo, my first try was to do this:

```
db.test.find({
  $and: [ 
    { "scores.value": {$gte: 8}}, 
    { "scores.value": {$lte: 10}} 
  ]
})
```

- Case [8, 10]: 2 records.
- Case [0, 1] : 0 records
- Case [5, 6] : 2 records

So there are some odd stuff here: first results suggests that my query actually returns scores with either of the condition satisfied (somewhat an $or instead of $and). But is that were true, I would have retrieved all records on the second case [0, 1] instead of 0. Obviously something I'm using the wrong way here, but if someone can explain me why, I'd be very happy.

Next query:

```
db.test.find({
  "scores": {
    $elemMatch: { 
      value: {$gte: 6.5, $lte: 6.8} 
    }
  }
})
```

- Case [8, 10]: 2 records.
- Case [0, 1] : 0 records
- Case [5, 6] : 0 records

For that one, everything is fine and works as documented / expected, but it does not answer my original use case.

So beside understanding what happened using the first query, does anyone knows a way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by understand what went wrong in your first attempt.

You were using Mongo's [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#arrays), what does this do?

> To specify or access an element of an array by the zero-based index position

Basically it evaluates all the arrays elements at once.

```
 $and: [ 
    { "scores.value": {$gte: 8}}, 
    { "scores.value": {$lte: 10}} 
  ]
```

Each of these expressions queries the entire array, meaning to satisfy it query all you need is a single value that's within the range.

What you can do is utilise the [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator and combined with `$elemMatch` look for elements to exclude, like so:

```
db.collection.find({
  "scores": {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $or: [
          {
            value: {
              $lt: 8
            }
          },
          {
            value: {
              $gt: 10
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zIqcHBZl4RM)

Answer (score 3):

Taking [8-10] example, as you mentioned you can write a query to find all "bad" documents where at least on score is not in [8-10] range:
That's the purpose of `elementMatch`.

"bad" document is ( score < 8 OR score > 10 ):

```js
db.collection.find({
  "scores": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $or: [ { value: { $lt: 8 }}, { value: { $gt: 10 }} ]
    }
  }
})
```

Then you can invert the condition with a `$not` to get the result you expected (reject "bad" documents):

```js
db.collection.find({
  "scores": { 
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $or: [ { value: { $lt: 8 }}, { value: { $gt: 10 }} ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zIqcHBZl4RM)